# How do I change visibility of an asp label with javascript with an onchange event of an asp textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling

I have the used css to set the display of the label to none
I am very new to js so I'm not 100% on my code for it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function strLen(field, count)
{
var str = document.getElementById("textbox1");
if(str.value.length > 2)
{
document.getElementById("errorLabel").style.display = 'inherit';
}
}
</script>
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" CssClass="style5" runat="server" MaxLength="10"         onchange="strLen()"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: do you want to make it visible or invisible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have arguments in your JS function, but you're not passing any arguments in the onchange event.

Apply the following code to your TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" CssClass="style5" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onkeyup="strLen(this, 2);"></asp:TextBox>
```

**METHOD #1**: Using a Label

Your error label should look like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="Exceeds max length" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

And then in your JavaScript function, you can do this:

**EDIT**: Had logic backwards - changed to: input.value.length > count ? "block" : "none";

```
strLen = function(input, count){
    var errorLabel = document.getElementById("<%=lblError.ClientID%>");
    if (errorLabel)
        errorLabel.style.display = input.value.length > count ? "block" : "none";
}
```

**METHOD #2**: Using a span instead of a Label

Or you could just use a span instead of a label, like this:

```
<span id="errorLabel" style="display:none;">Exceeds max length</span>
```

And change the JavaScript function to this:

**EDIT**: Had logic backwards - changed to: input.value.length > count ? "block" : "none";

```
strLen = function(input, count){
    var errorLabel = document.getElementById("errorLabel");
    if (errorLabel)
        errorLabel.style.display = input.value.length > count ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: Instead of lblError, use the ID of your error label. And don't forget to declare the tag as <%=  (very important)

Comment: alright I have added it like that, and there are no errors, but it does nothing when I type more than the characters in specified in the arguments (I assumed thats what that number was) Any suggestions as to why it may not be working quite right?

Comment: It's probably because you're doing it onchange. Change it to onkeyup.

Comment: It is still giving me no change in the label

Comment: How far into the method is it going? See edited answer for debug code.

Comment: Just to make sure that it isn't something obvious, in your example you wanted the label to appear afte typing 2 characters. Are you passing in 2 to the count parameter? My example is 200, so you would have to type in 200 characters before the label appeared.

Comment: the alerts aren't even coming up for me, there must be something I am missing or doing wrong

Comment: Yea, there's something wrong if you're not even making it into the function.

Comment: would it have anything to do with the asp thats being used, cause from looks, it looks decent to me, like it should atleast show the alerts... because visual studio says that onkeyup is not a valid attribute of element TextBox

Comment: I made another change. I tested it myself, so it does work. Instead of using UniqueID use ClientID in the JavaScript function. Assuming everything else is right, it should work after that.

Comment: @Joe W: See edited answer. I've provided two different techniques for making this work. I tested both, and if implemented correctly both work.

Comment: It doesnt work on the site that I need it for, but I made a blank site, and it works with it.. so theres something going on in my code i don't know

Comment: @Joe W: There must be something in the other site that's preventing it. Did you get my edit about the backwards logic? Sorry for so many edits, but I've been in the middle of two other things, and was a little careless. I think the code above should work fine now, so just look through your code carefully and make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: Yes I just caught that now, I was hoping it would fix it all but still something wrong..
I do thank you for the help you have given me, because I now know what to do once i figure out why my javascript isnt working.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck on getting it working. JavaScript is kind of tough to debug, but if you use alerts you can usually get to the bottom of things.

Comment: @Joe W: If you're all set with this problem, can you mark as answer? You'll get faster replies in the future if you always mark the working solution as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just deleted all the parts to the label and the textbox and made them from scratch... and now it works perfectly! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net 4, then you can set the ClientIdMode of the label to static and reference it like you are. See Rick's post here:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40

You can use a RegularExpressionValidator to validate the length of the textbox.. however based on your comment see the javascript solution below.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1026502.aspx

pure javascript - something like this should work fine.:

```
 <div id="lengthInfo" style="display:none">Too long!!</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function strLen(textBox) {
         var str = textBox.value;
         if (str.length > 2) {
             document.getElementById("lengthInfo").style.display = 'inline';
         }
         else {
             document.getElementById("lengthInfo").style.display = 'none';
         }
     }
</script>
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" CssClass="style5" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onkeyup="strLen(this)"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: What is trying to be accomplished is:
if someone enters in more than 2 characters display a message saying that if they are from the US, use the postal abbreviation, but because this is also available to customers outside the US we allow for longer abbreviations.
I have another version currently where the textbox has auto postback enabled and it works that way but you have to click out of the box, and then the screen refreshes

Comment: see my above edit - you can actually remove  ClientIDMode="Static" since we're passing in a 'this' reference and don't care about the naming of the textbox.

Comment: alright I have added it like that, and there are no errors, but it does nothing when I type more than 2 characters it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions as to why it may not be working quite right? Like I said before I am pretty new to this javascript

Comment: see my code edit above. you dont need a specific label (since if its a server control label and hidden it wont be rendered to html)